# access textbox(HTMLHelper) value using a class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, html-helper

How can I access "StudentID" value in JavaScript function(jQuery).

HTML:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Student.Models.vwStudent>>" %>

    <div class="divClass">
      <table class="tableClass">
      <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
        <tr class="trClass">
          <td class="tdClass">
            <%= Html.TextBox("StudentID") %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% } %>
      </table>
    </div>
```

JQuery:

```
 $('#ShowStudentID').click(function () {        
      $(".tdClass").each(function () {
          alert($(this).val());           
      });
 });
```

Master (Form):

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("SaveCommitment", "LPForm")) %>
<% { %>
<div>
<% Html.RenderPartial("DisplayStudents"); %>
</div>
<% } %>
<br/><br/>
<input type="button" id="ShowStudentID" name="ShowStudentID" value="Show StudentID" />
</div>
```

I have tried using text(), innerHTML() and innerText() methods but cant get this to working. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since your question deals with javascript/jQuery, and not C#/MVC, you should post your HTML as it is rendered on the client, rather than your view's source

Comment: What does the actual outputted HTML look like?

Comment: you should use text() or html() instead of val().

Comment: Also, what element has id of "ShowStudentID"? It's not in your html.

Comment: using text() works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/TTJV4/1/

Comment: @Raminson using html() gives me the following output: "<INPUT id=StudentID value=JD1122 name=StudentID>"

Comment: @MrOBrian It is a button on parent view: I have updated it above

Comment: @wirey using text() doesnt work with <%= Html.TextBox("StudentID") %>

Comment: what does <%= Html.TextBox("StudentID") %> output on the client side?

Comment: @wirey it returns empty string

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value of an input inside the .tdClass you can try the following:

```
 $('#ShowStudentID').click(function () {        
      $(".tdClass").find('input').each(function() {
          alert($(this).val());           
      });
 });
```

Comment: In addition to capturing input values What if I want to capture other elements values which are HTML Encoded? Is there anyway to achieving this for inputs and Html Encoded values?

Comment: @user793468  that's not possible, javascript has no access to the pre-processed codes.

Comment: I am able to access those encoded values if I remove ".find('input')"

Answer (score 0):

Easy and fast way to access it by ID:

```
$('#StudentID').val();
```